# Adding classes from a given array or an object

Tags: javascript

I want to add classes to elements based on a source array or object.
For example, it can be:

```
classesArr = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
```

or

```
classesObj = {class1: "class1", class2: "class2", class3: "class3"};
```

the way I currently do it is:

```
// for arrays
element = document.getElementById("myelement");

classesArr.forEach(className => {
    element.classList.add(className);
});
```

or

```
// for objects
element = document.getElementById("myelement");

for (const [key, className] of Object.entries(classesObj) {
    element.classList.add(className)
}
```

But perhaps there are some JavaScript tricks that can do it simpler (maybe even in 1 line?)

Comment: Do you have a project that uses these arrays/objects?

Comment: In my project I get these arrays/objects of classes from the backend and I want to add them to certain elements. You mean you want me to provide an example? I can try to create a snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re not using the keys of the returned 2D array of `Object.entries`, so you could use the flat `Object.values` instead.

More importantly, the `DOMTokenList.add` method takes a **list** as its argument already, so there is no need to explicitly iterate as you can just [**spread** the array for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/element/classlist) (`element.classList.add(...classesArr)`).

As a function, you could have the element being worked on be the argument so there wouldn’t be those loosely floating references to elements.

Comment: Oh that's nice, so in case it's an Object I do `element.classList.add(...Object.entries(classesObj))` ?

Comment: @B.DLiroy `Object.values`, but otherwise yes.

Comment: @SolomonUcko oops my bad! Yes `Object.values`, thank you